# How to link Posts to Authors

Tags: graphql, yaml, gatsby, relation

I'm trying to generate a page for each Authors including all their Posts - here's my setup:

- using `gatsby-transformer-yaml` to get my list of authors:

```
    {
      allAuthorsYaml {
        nodes {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
```

- using `gatsby-transformer-remark` to get my list of posts:

```
    {
      allFile(
        sort: { fields: childMarkdownRemark___frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
        filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "posts" } }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                author {
                  title
                  id
                }
                date
                location
                title
                slug
                tags
              }
              html
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

- my `author` node is being mapped successfully in my `frontmatter` using this in my `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
...
  mapping: {
    "MarkdownRemark.frontmatter.author": `AuthorsYaml`
  },
...
```

---

Now, what I would like to do is to get a list of posts for all my authors, using something like this:

```
    {
      allAuthorsYaml {
        nodes {
          id
          title
          posts {
            frontmatter {
              date
              location
              title
              slug
              tags
            }
            html
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

What would be the most effective way to achieve this - either following the suggested GraphQL query OR some alternative best practice?

Thanks!